# nav items in header not working

Tags: css, opacity

I have a strange issue .. I have a header with image background .. I wanted to add some opacity to that image and so I created another div (#main) before the header and gave it the same width and height as well as the absolute position and of course the background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) that is responsible for adding opacity . The problem is the header contains a nav bar , but now after applying that trick , these nav items can't be clicked neither hovered .. 
here is the css code :

```
 #main {
        height: 540px;
        width:100%;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        position:absolute;
    }
    header{
        margin:0;
        padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
        height: 540px;
        width:auto;
        background: url('../img/cover.png') center center;
        background-size: cover;
        color:white; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a `z-index` to your nav element, where navigation links are contained

```
nav {
    z-index:2;
    position:relative;
}
```

[**Fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7oafg6o9/1/)